# Bitcoin rpc-json for web javascript

Tags: json-rpc

So is there any js file that you can use to connect a json-rpc server on a client side website?

I seem to find one for PHP but not JavaScript or there isn't one?

Comment: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcoind-rpc

Comment: @renlord i just checked it out (sorry i was low on time) and this is for node.js it said or ill also work for web javascript?